# AS3: Maintain Checkbox state when returning to a frame with checkboxes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, checkbox

So I asked a question yesterday about how to control the state of some checkboxes here: [Getting Checkboxes to retain their state on return to frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746009/getting-checkboxes-to-retain-their-state-on-return-to-frame)

However this has caused another problem. Whilst the values of the checkboxes are retained, their relationship to the objects they represent is not.. for example, on return to the home screen the checkbox value will be filled in as true but the button that that checkbox represents won't be visible until I uncheck and recheck the box.

I've been trying to store the Boolean value of the checkbox in a variable and then re use it upon return to the screen but I just don't' understand enough of the syntax to get it work.

Looking at the code below I'm wondering whether it's because I'm setting the default state of the button visibility right at the start of the code to false? Do I need to get Area_1_Btn.visible to check for the Boolean state?

Any help greatly appreciated as I'm getting more and more frustrated at my lack of understanding heh.

```
import flash.events.Event;

/* Ensures that all checkboxes begin in the off state.*/
Area_1_Btn.visible = false;
Area_1_Chk.visible = true;
Area_2_Btn.visible = false;
Area_2_Chk.visible = true;
ShowAll_Chk.visible = true;

/* Defines the Show All Checkbox and sets states to true/false*/
ShowAll_Chk.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, toggleMulti, false, 0, true);
function toggleMulti(e:Event):void
{
    var SAC:Boolean = e.target.selected;
    if (SAC)
    {
        Area_1_Chk.selected = true;
        Area_1_Btn.visible = true;
        Area_2_Chk.selected = true;
        Area_2_Btn.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Area_1_Chk.selected = false;
        Area_1_Btn.visible = false;
        Area_2_Chk.selected = false;
        Area_2_Btn.visible = false;
    }
}

/* Toggles the button state*/
function toggleArea_1_Btn(e:Event):void
{
    var A1B:Boolean = e.target.selected;
    if (A1B)
    {
        Area_1_Btn.visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Area_1_Btn.visible = false;
    }
    /* previous method for toggling button state*/
}
function toggleArea_2_Btn(e:Event):void
{
    Area_2_Chk.selected ? Area_2_Btn.visible = true:Area_2_Btn.visible = false;
}

/* Listens to the state of the checkbox and switches the button on*/
Area_1_Chk.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, toggleArea_1_Btn, false, 0, true);
Area_2_Chk.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, toggleArea_2_Btn, false, 0, true);

/* Listens for a mouse click and then instructions function below*/
Area_1_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, A1_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);
Area_2_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, A2_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function A1_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
function A2_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

stop();
```

Comment: Need some additional information.  1.  What is the context of the code posted?  first frame of the main timeline? somewhere else?  Where do your checkboxes live?  main timeline (all frames?) a specific frame or set of frames on the main timeline?

Comment: The script lives in the first frame of the main timeline and is used to define the visibilty of clickable images (buttons) on a 'map' which then link to other frames with more information about the image clicked. 

At the moment the checkboxes live on all frames but are invisible after the first frame. This was done to retain their state. If I can wrap my head around using variables to retain the state of the button/image visibility then I fully intend to add that code to the check boxes as well.

Comment: Should all the checkboxes be visible on the first frame?

Comment: Yes. Basically the check boxes switch on all the images/buttons on the map. The user then clicks those buttons to be taken to a seperate frame containing information about the area of the map they clicked on.

When you first run the file you're presented with a load of unticked checkboxes and a blank background map. Checking the tick boxes overlays areas (buttons in the form of images) on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some optimizations and additions that should do the trick:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//a method you can call to set the visibility of all checkbox related items. Pass in false to hide them all
function showCheckBoxes(val:Boolean = true):void {
    Area_1_Chk.visible = val;
    Area_2_Chk.visible = val;
    ShowAll_Chk.visible = val;
    Area_1_Btn.visible = val;
    Area_2_Btn.visible = val;

    if(val) setButtonVisibility();  //if showing, show/hide the buttons based off the check box value
}

//this will update the button visibility based off the checkbox selected value.
function setButtonVisibility(e:Event = null):void {
    Area_1_Btn.visible = Area_1_Chk.selected;
    Area_2_Btn.visible = Area_2_Chk.selected;
}

function toggleMulti(e:Event):void {
    Area_1_Chk.selected = ShowAll_Chk.selected;
    Area_2_Chk.selected = ShowAll_Chk.selected;
    setButtonVisibility();
}

function buttonClick(e:Event):void {
    showCheckBoxes(false); //hide everything since we're moving to a new frame

    switch(e.currentTarget) {   //e.currentTarget is the button that was clicked
        case Area_1_Btn:
            gotoAndStop(2);
            break;

        case Area_1_Btn:
            gotoAndStop(3);
            break;
    }
}

//add all the listeners
ShowAll_Chk.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, toggleMulti, false, 0, true);
Area_1_Chk.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, setButtonVisibility, false, 0, true);
Area_2_Chk.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, setButtonVisibility, false, 0, true);
Area_1_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
Area_2_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);

showCheckBoxes(); //call this right now so the visibility updates when the frame loads.

stop();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All up I've been trying to get this last bit to work for longer than it took to come up with the entire rest of the code. 

Much apreciated